# How to write Junit Test case for a method

Tags: junit4

I am very new to Junit testing,Kindly let me know how to mock this method and test in JUNIT:
[image]

Comment: `void Abc(Objsect o) {
        Attr[] attrd= o.changeAttr();
        if (attrd.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < attrd.length; i++) {
                if (attrd[i].toString().contains(PropertyMessage.fsc_pra)) {
                    ifModified = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can write test classes like this

```
public class MyTests {    
  @Test
  public void multiplicationOfZeroIntegersShouldReturnZero() {
       MyClass tester = new MyClass(); // MyClass is tested

       // assert statements
       assertEquals(0, tester.multiply(10, 0), "10 x 0 must be 0");
       assertEquals(0, tester.multiply(0, 10), "0 x 10 must be 0");
       assertEquals(0, tester.multiply(0, 0), "0 x 0 must be 0");
  }
}
```

for more just check this link 
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Comment: What about using mock?

Comment: here we have mocked our class object using code . by the way you can use some mocking framework to do this like Mokito..  https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html?source=post_page---------------------------

Comment: so how can I test this method using mocking framework?